# Live streaming changes to https automatically

Tags: html, jquery, http, recursion, html5-audio

I am trying to get a live stream from an online radio link. When I run the URL in the browser, I get it playing but if I insert in a HTML audio player then it changes the URL from HTTP to HTTPS and does not play it.
here is an example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://80sbeats.cyberbeats.net:8000/stream?icy=http" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Any idea why it does not play it?

Comment: Strange because in my case it works. Maybe it is something on the server configuration or do you have also other code in your HTML file that may occur an error?

Comment: @kabr8 Does the above play for you?

Comment: No not the above, but if I make an HTML file and open it works also works when I start it by the webstorm  HTML boilerplate.

Comment: @kabr8 It doesn't play for me even if I save it in a file.

Comment: Strange strange, I tested it in three browsers now(Firefox, Chrome, Edge) all works for me, so maybe it is a system problem, so can you specify your browser system, system version, etc.

Comment: @kabr8 I'm using the latest version of Chrome. Also checked it on Edge and IE. Same results. I wonder if it has something to do with CORS.

Comment: You shouldn't mix HTTP and HTTPS on the same page (it's a page security issue, and most browsers give a warning in console of their Delevoper Tools panel). Did you test in Chrome? Try a basic html page with just `<audio>` tag in the body and use same audio link, does it now work?